# Get name of weekday in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I can get week number using extract dow function in netezza for a date.

Select extract(Dow from date) from table

How can I get name of the weekday?

Comment: There's no standard SQL for that — you'd normally JOIN on a table with day-names in whatever language(s) you like — but perhaps Netezza has an extension for it (not that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried with a date datatype, but to get the day name from a timestamp you would use

```
select to_char(date, 'Day') from table
```

That should give results of Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc.  Try it with your date column and please let us know if it works.

Comment: Gives lower case strings "monday", "tuesday" etc.  Note that the DOW is Sun(1)..Sat(7) whereas if you're using MSSQL it is Mon(0)..Sun(6) (same as Python Pandas).

Comment: @DavidJ: In MSSQL the first day of the week is configurable, using the DATEFIRST setting.  You can make any day of the week the first day.  Additionally, the WEEKDAY and DATEPART functions that return the day of the week can return 1 - 7 if you want them to.